# For a Greenhouse, would PE plastic cloth be suitable for a cheap sollution?

Tags: sunlight, greenhouse

I,ve always gotten along just fine without a greenhouse. Recently I've found the need to wanting a greenhouse, cheap but also large that can at least hold up for a couple years or more.

Ive recently been looking into polyethylene cloth, (plastic with mesh).
I was curious if this would last long enough and whether or not there is a spray that is uv protective for this kind of material. If so without damaging it,  what brand has a good uv sun protectant?

Answer (score 2):

Ive found the 303 formula from walmart has plastic protection and have looked into pe cloth also formidable to pp cloth. It is tear resistant and sun resistant for a good hope of 4 years. But its color im looking into could be negative,  the kind I am looking at is green which can be negative in a neutral way. Some say plants will reflect green light. I say different,  rays penetrate regardless, heat is a big factor and even if the color isnt white clear or red as people abide by, I beleive it to be suitable for my purposes. Further input on this material and a spray for better protecting it specific upon its material would be appreciated still,

Thankyou.

Comment: How much are you paying per square foot? Actual greenhouse film with the proper treatments can be had for 11-12 cents. That's guaranteed for 4 years and often goes 6 or more.

Comment: I do believe the film is 6mm,  it is preset for setup, as it is portable. The length is 20' by 10' wide and is only $169.99.  So its Square footage would be,  what? 200sq feet. Through Aosom it is mainly sold.  I was reading that pe does come in 4mm which only last a couple years,  there is no exact description of this product and happens to be no questionare for it.  Though normal overlay is and should be 6mm thickness.  Florida sun is brutal on my plants.  So being that the green house in question happens to be green, which isnt the greatest,  it shall keep them warm and safe still.

Comment: After a year I would like to have a protective spray for upkeep in order to make sure this cheapy greenhouse stays more well maintained.  I dont know how many people bother with this kind of stuff,  most Id assume will completely go balls out on it or go home.  Lets say this is just a test for me, an experiment.  Nessasary but not so so much.  More like an interest.

Comment: So you are paying 85 cents a square foot for a product not actually suitable, rather than the 11-12 cents that the right product costs. And then you want to pay extra every year for some mythical spray on solution... ???

Comment: As i have said, I do believe it to be the correct material it also includes the steel frame which accounts for cost and tie downs aswell,  not to mention rope ups, velcro and zippers.  Its just hard to ask the company directly,  Im waiting on an email back to find out if its 6mm or not. By the by,  I do not know what you mean by "Mythical Spray" theres nothing mythical about it, that would suggest it doesnt exist,  which in fact it does. I was curious if anybody knew of a decent affordable brand besides the walmart 303 plastic uv protectant. Something that specifies the use on PE material.

Comment: Also, if I had to pay 20 bucks for a bottle of spray every year,  that wouldnt be much of an issue. 20 or even 30 bucks for a whole year isnt much of anything.

Comment: @Ecnerwal is right on.  We used El Cheapo plastic last year just to last for the rest of the year.  In 2 months the UV destroyed the south side of our greenhouse skin.  Snow hit and it completely imploded. My perennials in the greenhouse had a tough time, I lost half of them...even EVEN mint!!  We just purchased some good stuff and could only afford to do half, the south side until we can afford in a month or two for the North side.  Went the extra mile by putting soft, thin insulation between the plastic and wood then on top of the plastic installed 'batten'.  Wind movement won't deteriorate.

Comment: Hmm. Thats a sad story. Yeah,  I hate hearing stuff like that. I grow all types of things, mainly peppers of all variety. So as a thought. Peppers get burnt up in full on sun all the time,  not always but it does harm them. A green house in order to keep them nice and warm with a little humidity would be something i wanna push foward to get that nice dark green back.  I appreciate your comment. I have flower beds and bushes all around my house, i hate when things dont survive. Would you both suggest. I build my own using a material alone instead of a kit? If I do get a kit it will have a frame

Comment: After the greenhouse material that comes with the kit deteriorates. I could use the frame and use a better material to overlay. Because for me to get a standing structure is more then likely going to be costly especially since i need a large unit. What would you suggest? Add a answer instead of commenting back in order to create a shorter comment section again before this one becomes a little too long. Would be better suiting for it is a question aswell

Comment: Been thinking of using a netted braid material . With a 8 year uv warranty. Im going to fit a wooden shed together and build my own frame itll be sturdy and I will have a good material. I can get a 26 foot roll by 20 feet for 92 dollars. Itll be perfect.